# ffmpeg-php won't start after upgrading php from 5.1.6 to 5.2.13

Tags: centos, ffmpeg, php

CentOS 5, installed ffmpeg and compiled the ffmpeg.so. Everything works fine.
Then upgrade the php to 5.2.13 (using an external repository)

recompiled ffmpeg.so but now when trying to load php:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to rollback, as there is no real php-5.2.13 rpm provided by rhel/centos

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution, 
phpize -clean,
rm the so file.

then reinstalling.